# Extending a google spreadsheet into a google web app

Tags: javascript, import, google-apps-script, webapp2

I was coding using the google scripts, when I came across a problem I've been struggling with for a couple days now. I am using Code.gs (a default page in creating a web app in google), when I called in data from a google spreadsheet to try and display it on a webpage. I had no problems with calling in the data add storing it into a array but now I am struggling with trying to return it to my javascript code. Can this be done or is there something else I can do to fix it? My code is below.

```js
function getContents()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xum5t4a83CjoU4EfGd50f4ef885F00d0erAvUYX0JAU/edit#gid=0&vpid=A1');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      var education = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
         if (values[i][j]) {
            if(j==1){
                education[education.length] = values[i][j];
            }
         }         
       }
     }
   Logger.log(education);
   return education;
 }
```

From that Code.gs code i want it to return it to a Javascript function that says this:

```js
function onNew(){
    var input = google.script.run.getContents();
    for(var = 0; i<input.length; i++)
    {
       $("#main").append("<div id='class'>"+input[i]+"</div>);
    }
  }
```

and whenever I try to run it says that it causes an error because it is undefined. Thanks in advance! Anything helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `withSuccessHandler()`.  Your variable `input` will not receive the return from `google.script.run.getContents()`

Separate out the client side code into two functions:

### HTML Script

```
function onNew() {
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(appendEducationHTML)
    .getContents();
};

function appendEducationHTML(returnedInfo) {
  console.log('returnedInfo type is: ' + typeof returnedInfo);
  console.log('returnedInfo: ' + returnedInfo);

  //If return is a string.  Convert it back into an array
  //returnedInfo = returnedInfo.split(",");

  for (var = 0;i < returnedInfo.length; i++) {
    $("#main").append("<div id='class'>"+returnedInfo[i]+"</div>);
  };
};
```